# Booting windows 10 after deleting linux dualboot partition

Tags: windows, grubrescue

I had Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual booting on my laptop with grub.
I decided to go back to just Windows 10, hence I deleted the Ubuntu partitions.
Upon restarting my computer I am met with `Error: no such partition` and grub rescue.

I believe the Windows partition is okay but grub doesn't know how to navigate there.
 
How to I get back to my Windows OS through grub rescue, and how do I remove grub?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, just use UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12 and choose Windows. To remove Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi If BIOS, follow answer below using your Windows repair disk or install disk and repair console to restore Windows boot loader to MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a bootable USB drive/CD/DVD with the exact same version Windows that you got installed on your PC. Boot from that CD/DVD/USB. Select your language and press Next. Then click on **Repair your computer** option in bottom left. Now you have to find and open **Command Prompt**. It is usually under **Advanced options** in Windows 8,8.1,10.

In the Command Prompt run these commands-

> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /rebuildbcd
>
> exit

Then restart your PC.

**Note: This will only work on BIOS/MBR based dual-boot system. If you have UEFI based dual-boot follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi) link.**